# c: segmentation fault (selection sort)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
#include<stdio.h>
void selsort(int a[],int s)
{
    int min,temp,i,j;       
    for(i = 0; i < s ; i++)
    {
        min = 0;
        for(j = i+1 ; j < s; j++)
        {
            if(min > a[j])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[min];
        a[min] = temp;
        for (j=0;j<s;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");   

    }
}
main()
{
        int i,a[5];
        int size = 5;
        printf("Enter elements of the array");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        selsort(a[5],size);
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
selsort.c:35:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘selsort’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
selsort.c:2:1: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

any tips on how to avoid this problem in the future will be really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling your function like this:

```
selsort(a, size);
```

`a[5]` means "element at index 5" (past the end of your array, by the way: the largest legal element in `int a[5]` is at index `4`).

You should also replace

```
min = 0;
```

with

```
min = i;
```

and use it like this:

```
if(a[min] > a[j]) ...
```

Comment: @user1905568 You are welcome! If your problem is solved, you may want to accept an answer by clicking the check mark to indicate that you are no longer looking for an improved answer, and to earn a brand-new badge on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the function call `selsort(a[5], size);` you are only passing the 5th [nonexistent] member of a.  You want `selsort(a, size);`